# I need a solution to in-depth scan into Drupal git repositories to find useful code snippets

Tags: version-control

I'm looking to find out the best solutions to in-depth search into git repositories for code snippets: inside Drupal custom modules, revisions, contribs, themes, profiles.

As far as I know, Drupal no longer uses CVS/SVM but switched to git instead.

I am working on a Windows machine, but I commit/checkout to linux server using tortoiseSVN.

There is an old nice tutorial movie by Jonathan Lambert about how to search into SVN on GotDrupal.com on how to search into http://www.searchdrupal.org/ but searchdrupal.org no longer exists.

I need to know how you guys are building up modules using other people's snippets and how do you find it.
Any solution is precious to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[drupalcontrib.org](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal) is a nice place to find functions used within contributed modules as well as the core Drupal API.  It has helped me out in the past

Comment: Very nice...I hope it covers all the 9000+ Drupal modules and repos.